# htaccess mod rewrite - Fake Directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this: http://www.domain.com/index.php?token=123
I want to rewrite the url to this: http://www.domain.com/123 or http://www.domain.com/123/
With this htaccess i can access http://www.domain.com/123/ but my css is then not loaded.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d

RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$  index.php?token=$1 [L]
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I guess right than is your problem that you link relativ to your css file. So you need to correct the path to your css file.

Comment: I don't want to use a absolute path. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You could try to add the prefix `../`. So if your link to the css file like `css/myfile.css` you need to use `../css/myfile.css`. But this is equal to `/css/myfile.css` and you need 2 bytes less.

Comment: The Problem is, that it can be blank. Now it only works if i access http://www.domain.com/123/ and this ain't work anymore http://www.domain.com/

Comment: btw.. all my javascript (with relative paths) don't work anymore :D

Comment: All includes have the same rules. So far is IMHO absolut path the only way to slove your problem.

Comment: it can't be the only way.. ? I just have to overwrite the htaccess, but don't know how.. isn't there any other option?

Comment: Well there would be ways to achive that but I would not create multiple urls for the same files. So your clients could simple cache the css/js files without reloading them.

Comment: How would you handle this? I just need to write a variable(hash, GET-varaible, .. ?) from the url into a HTML-textbox. The Variable should be get from the url(http://www.domain.com/PUTTHISTOTEXTBOX). Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment. I'll have to go now. I'll be back later or tomorrow.

Comment: Du kommst ja aus Deutschland.. Ich möchte eine Variable aus der URL herauslesen und in eine Textbox schreiben. Also ich habe eine index.php Seite im root verzeichnis(root: http://www.domain.com). Nun wenn ich beispielsweise http://www.domain.com/123234234/ aurufe, soll nicht der "Ornder" geöffnet werden(welcher gar nicht exisitert), sondern der Wert 123234234 soll in die Textbox geschriebe werden. Ich dachte ich löse das über .htaccess und GET-Variabeln.. Da mein kleines Script später mal auf mehreren Servern laufen wird, möchte ich keine absolute Pfäde benutzen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23595/discussion-between-rekire-and-user1515190)